# TinyMCE not working with ajax in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tinymce

When I use TinyMCE in combination with ajax in IE 11 it will constantly give errors like: `SCRIPT70: Access denied File: tinymce.js, Line: 13832, Column: 42`. It only occurs in IE 11 and in IE 10 (we don't support old IE browsers).

When I google this problem or search on stackoverflow.com I find the same problems with IE 7, 8 etc. Only no solution worked for me.

How to make TinyMCE ajax proof so it works in IE 11 and 10?

What I tried so far:

```
//found this on stackoverflow but it does not seem to work for me
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, 0);                    
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 0);
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, 1);                    
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 1);
```

I currently have 2 TinyMCE editors:

[image]

This is how I initialize them (This code is loaded with ajax inside the form which is inserted with jquery.html() method):

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    mode:'exact',
    plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste microBoatImages'
    ],
    style_formats: [
        {title: 'Image Left', selector: 'img', styles: {
            'float' : 'left', 
            'margin': '0 10px 0 10px'
        }},
        {title: 'Image Right', selector: 'img', styles: {
            'float' : 'right', 
            'margin': '0 10px 0 10px'
        }}
    ],
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough forecolor backcolor | charmap pagebreak hr | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | link styleselect image microBoatImages | preview code',
    relative_urls: false
});
```

**#update**

The TinyMCE documentation says that I have to use `tinymce.remove();`. But this also gives me a Access denied error in IE.

Comment: what is at `Line: 13832`?

Comment: @Jai These errors occur on multiple lines. For example on this line 27796: `return this.bodyElement || this.getDoc().body;` where IE can not access the body of the editor.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in IE11 if I call tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, id), the next postback link I click refuses to work, any other does. If you do call it enough times eventually I get a black flashing rectangle in the top left of the window.